# Solr highlighting in solr config

Tags: solr, config, highlight

I am going to enable highlighting in all my queries and don't want to put it all the times in the url, is there any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add it as a defaults in the request handler, so it will be applicable to all urls you execute :-

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>

   <!-- Highlighting Defaults -->
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>     
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Sorry if I ask, what does the `f.name` prefix mean in `f.name.hl.fragsize`?

Comment: Some parameters may be overriden on a per-field basis with the following syntax:

f.<fieldName>.<originalParam>=<value> .... so name is a field name.